# Injecting a variable inside a string, in a specific location

Tags: python

I have this line:

```
assert response.headers['Content-Disposition'] == 'attachment; filename=myFile.txt'
```

In the second string of the line (`'attachment; filename=myFile.txt'`)

I want to remove the hardcoded filename (`myFile.txt`) and replace it with a variable that i have.

Like printf() in C, in a way, replacing the string at that exact location with a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [`f`-string](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings):

```
fileName = 'myFile.txt'
# ...
assert response.headers['Content-Disposition'] == f'attachment; filename={fileName}'
```